# Set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector JBoss EAP6

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, jboss-eap-6

I have a main page with many elements included to another page but with different parameters using jsf 2.2 and it works with seam & jboss 5, but with jboss EAP6 (without seam) it gives me those errors :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB002004: More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for a single request (512) were detected. Any parameters beyond this limit have been ignored. To change this limit, set the maxParameterCount attribute on the Connector.
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.addParameter(Parameters.java:184)
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:360)
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:213)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2858)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1279)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:349)
com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.containsKey(RequestParameterMap.java:99)
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.containsKey(Collections.java:1337)
org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.getConversationId(WeldPhaseListener.java:171)
org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:99)
org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:85)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

Any idea to solve these?

I searched and I have found this :

```
<system-properties>
 <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="5000"/>
</system-properties>
```

I found that I have to add that to standalone.xml but when I tried it doesn't start.

Comment: it works by adding :

<system-properties>
 <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="5000"/>
</system-properties>

juste after </extensions> balise but my n+1 want that i don't touche to the standalone file and solve that juste by finding a solution ,

i have 3 jsf pages:

in the first i include the seconde and passing 4 parametters and i use juste to in the seconde page and i include the tirde page and i pass tow others param whitch i use in the tird page 

page1(parm1,2,3,4) includes page2(i use param 1,2 and i pass param 3,4) includes page 3(i use parm 3,4)